# Regular Expression on search criteria (comes after and comes before)

Tags: java, regex

I have dropdown values of "comes after" and "comes before" for searching the text in textbox which I entered.
For example, in textbox, I've values like `sam beach center`, `aloe beach` and `center of pearl`. In Java, I've implemented

```
public static List<Reference> getComesAfterList(List<Reference> items, String searchField){
        ArrayList<Reference> matchingList = new ArrayList<Reference>(items.size());
            Iterator<Reference> refDataItems = items.iterator();
        String searchFieldLower = searchField.trim().toLowerCase();
        while (refDataItems.hasNext()) {
                 reference = refDataItems.next();
             try {
                     description = (String)reference.getValue(Reference.USERDESCRIPTION);
             }
        catch (Exception exc) {                          
                    throw new RuntimeException(exec);
             }
        if (description.matches("searchFieldLower(?=description)"))     
        //comes after scenerio->A(?=B)Find expression A where expression B follows 
        {
                    matchingList.add(reference);
                }
    }
}

//comes before case

public static List<Reference> getComesBeforeList(List<Reference> items, String searchField){
        ArrayList<Reference> matchingList = new ArrayList<Reference>(items.size());
            Iterator<Reference> refDataItems = items.iterator();
        String searchFieldLower = searchField.trim().toLowerCase();
        while (refDataItems.hasNext()) {
                 reference = refDataItems.next();
             try {
                     description = (String)reference.getValue(Reference.USERDESCRIPTION);
             }
        catch (Exception exc) {                          
                    throw new RuntimeException(exec);
             }
        if (description.matches("(?<=searchFieldLower)description"))    
        //comes before scenerio->(?<=B)A Find expression A where expression B precedes
        {
                    matchingList.add(reference);
                }
    }
}
```

How to search text criteria like this? Is there any way other than regular expression? Help me to solve this.

Comment: You create invalid regex, you should use `description.matches("(?<="+searchFieldLower+")"+description)` if you want to use varables in it.  Also, `matches()` will return `true` only if whole string match with regex, so there is no sense to use lookarounds with it.

Comment: Whats more regex will not work in this case at all, because you try to use regex on different String objects (if I understood your code properly).  You check if `String description` content, is preceded by content of `searchFieldLower`, but this is not possible! In this case, I would rather try with `ArrayList.listIterator()`, and compare `next()` or `previous()` values from list with `searchFieldLower`. Or you can use regex on whole textbox content, to look for searched values